# Handling null values with Javascript and Zapier

Tags: javascript

I am working on a script for Zapier where I want to pass order information. I am supporting up to three order items. The issue is if there is only one order item, blank values are still being passed for the two other items, creating blank rows. Here is what I have so far:

```
  url: 'https://edapi.campaigner.com/v1/Orders',
  method: 'POST',

  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'Accept': 'application/json',
    'X-API-KEY': bundle.authData.ApiKey
    },
    params: {
    'ApiKey': bundle.authData.ApiKey
    },
    body: {
  'EmailAddress': bundle.inputData.EmailAddress,
  'OrderNumber': bundle.inputData.OrderNumber,
  'PurchaseDate': bundle.inputData.PurchaseDate,
  'TotalAmount': bundle.inputData.TotalAmount,
  'Items':[
      {"ProductName": bundle.inputData.ProductName,
      "SKU": bundle.inputData.SKU2,
      "Quantity": bundle.inputData.Quantity,
      "UnitPrice": bundle.inputData.UnitPrice,
      "Status": bundle.inputData.Status},
      
      {"ProductName": bundle.inputData.ProductName2,
      "SKU": bundle.inputData.SKU2,
      "Quantity": bundle.inputData.Quantity2,
      "UnitPrice": bundle.inputData.UnitPrice2,
      "Status": bundle.inputData.Status2},
      
       {"ProductName": bundle.inputData.ProductName3,
      "SKU": bundle.inputData.SKU3,
      "Quantity": bundle.inputData.Quantity3,
      "UnitPrice": bundle.inputData.UnitPrice3,
      "Status": bundle.inputData.Status2},
  ]
    
    }

};


return z.request(options)
  .then((response) => {
    response.throwForStatus();
    const results = response.json;
    // You can do any parsing you need for results here before returning them
    return results;
  });
```

I am thinking that I need an if statement of maybe or something?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get help on this.

```
const options = {
    url: 'https://edapi.campaigner.com/v1/Orders',  
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'X-API-KEY': bundle.authData.ApiKey
    },
    params: {
        'ApiKey': bundle.authData.ApiKey
    },
    body: {
        'EmailAddress': bundle.inputData.EmailAddress,  
        'OrderNumber': bundle.inputData.OrderNumber,
        'PurchaseDate': bundle.inputData.PurchaseDate,
        'TotalAmount': bundle.inputData.TotalAmount,
        'Items':[],
    }
};
// Add Items to array if they exist
if (bundle.inputData.ProductName) {
    options.body.Items.push({
        "ProductName": bundle.inputData.ProductName,
        "SKU": bundle.inputData.SKU,
        "Quantity": bundle.inputData.Quantity,
        "UnitPrice": bundle.inputData.UnitPrice,
        "Status": bundle.inputData.Status});
}
if (bundle.inputData.ProductName2) {
    options.body.Items.push({
        "ProductName": bundle.inputData.ProductName2,
        "SKU": bundle.inputData.SKU2,
        "Quantity": bundle.inputData.Quantity2,
        "UnitPrice": bundle.inputData.UnitPrice2,
        "Status": bundle.inputData.Status2});
}
if (bundle.inputData.ProductName3) {
    options.body.Items.push({
        "ProductName": bundle.inputData.ProductName3,
        "SKU": bundle.inputData.SKU3,
        "Quantity": bundle.inputData.Quantity3,
        "UnitPrice": bundle.inputData.UnitPrice3,
        "Status": bundle.inputData.Status3});
}
return z.request(options)
    .then((response) => {
        response.throwForStatus();
        const results = response.json;
        // You can do any parsing you need for results here before returning them
        return results;
    });
```